# Enable hibernate logging with spring data?

Tags: java

I am trying to set the hibernate logging of SQL statements in my springboot and springdata application.

I setting the following properties in the application.properties file:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

But somehow they are not getting picked up and no sql logs are coming.
Have tried setting spring.jpa.show-sql property also, but does'nt seem to work.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>in.abcd</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
              <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: set this property `spring.jpa.show-sql` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html

Comment: Have tried it, does'nt work either

Answer (score 5):

With Hibernate 6 following config can be used in SpringBoot3:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=trace
```

Answer (score 3):

Where you declare your entity manager bean, add the following properties.

```xml
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Or in Java annotations

```java
@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(HIBERNATE_ENTITIES);
        log.info("Created entity manager successfully");
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        //Properties to show SQL format of tables on deploy
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true); // Mark as true to log hibernate queries
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true); // Mark as true to log hibernate queries
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
```

Edit: Since you aren't using an entity manager, you can do this directly on your Configuration

````java
    private SessionFactory createSessionFactory(String options) {
      Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
      configuration.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql", "true");
      configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");


      StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
          .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
      SessionFactory sessionFactory = `enter code here`configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
      return sessionFactory;
    }```
````

Comment: Not sure, I dont have an entity manager. I am using spring data.

Comment: Anyways I have added the bean in the dbconfig file, what is 'HIBERNATE_ENTITIES' ?

Comment: I edited the answer.
`HIBERNATE_ENTITIES` is the basePackageClasses path to the package where you store your entities

Comment: Configuration configuration = new Configuration(); -> Error in this line "Configuration is abstract, cannot be instantiated"

Comment: `spring.jpa.show-sql = true` makes the logging with new lines so.. it's easy to recognize for us.

Answer (score 2):

Using the logger this should suffice

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

---

Or, using `spring.jpa` properties, you could use them like this:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

Additionally, to beautify or pretty print the SQL, we can add:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```